# chi-squared test P-value

Tags: python

when i use stats.cdf and ppf,I found that the data I calculated does not match the data in the table。

```
print(stats.chi2.cdf(6.843971445482956,19))
# 0.005000000000000003
print(stats.chi2.cdf(38.58225655493424,19))
# 0.995
print(stats.chi2.ppf(0.005,19))
# 6.843971445482955
print(stats.chi2.ppf(0.995,19))
# 38.58225655493424
```

But in the table, the chi-square value corresponding to p = 0.995 and V = 19 is 6.84

I also found that when v is the same in the table, the larger the p, the smaller the chi-square value. Isn't the meaning of p from the left to the area of the sample statistics?

Comment: What table? Where do you get these values from? Note that 0.005 == 1 - 0.995.

Comment: I think this is more of a stats question than a python question, but you should look at `stats.chi2.sf` and `stats.chi2.isf`

Comment: The chi-square statistic can only have positive values, so in this case the p value is the area under the null hypothesis chi-square density function *to the right* of the observed value.